# Differentiate arguments in SPASS prover formula

Tags: first-order-logic, automated-theorem-proving

I have a formula in FOL:
$\forall x \exists y: B(x) \implies C(y)$
and in SPASS: `forall([X], exists[Y], implies(B(X),C(Y)))`

I want to check the formula: $\exists x: B(X) \implies C(X)$ and in SPASS `exists([X], implies(B(X), C(X)))`

The problem is I want to determine that `X` and `Y` are different (like in my first formula) and I want to be the second formula *false* because of the fact, that B and C are for the same `X`: $B(X) => C(X)$ but my first formula said that it should be different.

Is there a way to tell SPASS that these arguments should be different?